# Small Data training in CMU Sphinx

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4, pocketsphinx

I have installed `sphinxbase`, `sphinxtrain` and `pocketsphinx` in `Linux (Ubuntu)`. Now I am trying to train data with speechcorps,transcriptions, dictionary etc obtained from **VOXFORGE**. (My etc and wav folder's data is obtained from **VOXFORGE**)

As I am new so I just want to train data and get some results with few line of transcripts and few wav files.  let say 10 wav file and 10 transcript lines cosponsoring to it. Like this person in doing in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAHH6-t9jK0)
but when I run `sphinxtrain` then I am getting error.

```
Estimated Total Hours Training: 0.07021431623931
    This is a small amount of data, no comment at this time
```

[image]

If I do `CFG_CD_TRAIN= no` I dont know what it means.

**What changes I need to make? So I am able to remove this error.**

PS: I can not add more data because I want to see some results first for my better understanding the whole scenario.

Answer (score 2):

> Not enough data for the training, we can only train CI models

You need at least 30 minutes of audio data to train CI models. Alternatively, you can set CFG_CD_TRAIN to "no".

Comment: But why I am not getting any results. It just create feat folder and put some mfc files there. 
But I am expecting some results. I am new thing might seem silly to you but for me its important. Thanks.

Comment: I have added picture and see it says Error

Comment: I've edited the answer. I checked sphinx's code, so the answer's definite.